# Does $\sum \frac{n!e^n}{n^n}$ converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have tried root and ratio test but they were inconclusive.
thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Why do you claim that those tests are inconclusive? Please show us your computations.

Comment: are you familiar with Stirling approximation?

Comment: Do you know Stirling's approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Stirling's formula*, you should find that
$$\frac{n!\,\mathrm e^n}{n^n}\sim_\infty\sqrt{2\pi n},$$
so it diverges trivially.